# Ideas for how to show autocomplete suggestions and validation messages in a clean way

Tags: interaction-design

I'm currently working on an assignment for a company that I'm applying to. I need to have a text input with a submit button that shows suggestions as the user types but it also needs to shows validation messages based on what the user types. I'm looking for suggestions on a clean way on how to show this.

Here's my current layout:

[image]

If it's not clear, the textbox is on the left with the suggestions under it, the submit button is in the middle and the validation message is on the right. I could put the validation message below the suggestions but that might look a bit crowded. Any other suggestions? It's not terrible the way it is but it looks a little awkward to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can display the error message inside the dropdown if the typed text is incorrect and doesn't find any results.

You can also suggest them to add the incorrect option as an option if that is the case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a very useful suggestion